# Yii2 queue TTR attribute doesn't applies

Tags: yii2

I have the following queue config:

```
 'queue' => [
            'class' => \yii\queue\db\Queue::class,
            'db' => 'db',
            'tableName' => '{{%queue}}', 
            'channel' => 'default',
            'mutex' => \yii\mutex\MysqlMutex::class,
            'ttr' => 14400,
        ],
```

I wrote simple job that outputs current time in the console.
use yii\queue\JobInterface;
use yii\queue\Queue;

```
class DummyTimer implements JobInterface
{
    public function run()
    {
        $strtime = time();
        while($strtime + (4*60*60) > time())
            echo date('H:i:s') . "\r\n";

    }

    public function execute($queue)
    {
        $this->run();
    }
}
```

It runs only 300 seconds, and then gets killed with the next output in terminal:

> 2020-05-27 23:29:51 [8] app\modules\queue\DummyTimer (attempt: 1, pid:
>   7637) - Error
>   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException: The process "'/usr/bin/php7.2' 'yii' 'queue/exec' '8' '300' '1' '7637'
>   '--color=1' '--verbose=1'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

So how to increase maximum lifetime of a job?

Comment: Okay, looks like i'm still able to set ttr the next way: `\Yii::$app->queue->delay($delay)->ttr($ttr)->push();`

Answer (score 2):

The original solution should be working just fine:

```
 'queue' => [
        'class' => \yii\queue\db\Queue::class,
        'db' => 'db',
        'tableName' => '{{%queue}}', 
        'channel' => 'default',
        'mutex' => \yii\mutex\MysqlMutex::class,
        'ttr' => 14400,
    ],
```

Stumbled upon the same issue and seemed that ttr in queue config did not work. But What I forgot to do was to **re-start the queue** process after changing the config. Works just fine with the configuration change if the queue is properly re-loaded with the new configuration.

Comment: How did you "restart the Queue" ?